# Pull object from array with inner and outer condition

Tags: mongodb, go

I have the following mongodb collection (`myCollection`):

```
[
   {
      "_id":"1",
      "name":"one",
      "values":[
         {
            "property":"a9",
            "value":8
         },
         {
            "property":"a2",
            "value":8
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"2",
      "name=":"two",
      "values":[
         {
            "property":"a1",
            "value":9
         },
         {
            "property":"a3",
            "value":9
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"4",
      "name":"four",
      "values":[
         {
            "property":"a4",
            "value":4
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I would like to remove (`$pull`) from `values` array the object with `values.property = a3` and `name = two`.

So, `{"property":"a3", "value":9}` object should be removed from `values` array of `_id` = 2.

This is my approach in `go` lang but it does not work:

```
myCollection.UpdateOne(context.TODO(),
    bson.M{"name": "two", "values.propery": "a3"},
    bson.D{bson.E{Key: "$pull", Value: "values.$"}},
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shell:

```
db.collection.update(
{
  "name": "two",
  "values.property": "a3",
},
{
  $pull: {
    "values": {
      "property": "a3",
    },
  },
})
```

go:

```
    filter := map[string]interface{}{
        "name":            "two",
        "values.property": "a3",
    }

    update := map[string]interface{}{
        "$pull": map[string]interface{}{
            "values": map[string]interface{}{
                "property": "a3",
            },
        },
    }

    myCollection.UpdateOne(
        context.TODO(),
        filter,
        update,
    )
```